# Are named search queries a Searchkick feature?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, searchkick

In Searchkick, are [named search queries](https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/search-apis/named-queries/) (`_name`) a feature?

If so, how are they performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, the OP asked the same question in the [searchkick repo](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/1650) and got an answer there.

The idea is to leverage [advanced search](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#advanced-search) which provide full flexibility when specifying the query, i.e. to add a `_name` for instance. Since it's only for debugging purposes, it's perfectly ok.

Comment: Thank you Val, happy to see the searchkick community is so nice, I will not double post.